# Passport.js code for local stratergy not working correctly for Login module

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

So I was trying to implement user authentication for my project by following the video tutorial by "Web Dev Simplified"- https://youtu.be/-RCnNyD0L-s?t=1011

And I've used the exact same code as him(except I've used mysql database to store data, while he used an array). All of the code for registering a user works fine, but the login part doesn't work.
All the passport configuration code is written in the passport-config.js file.

The problem is that my `getUserById` function in passport-config.js file doesn't return a user even when there is one in the result returned by the `mysql.query()` function (I can confirm it because `console.log(result[0])` in app.js actually prints the user object). When I `console.log(user)` in passport-config.js file, it prints `undefined`.

I think I know what the problem is, but don't know how to fix it. As evident from the terminal snippet(attached below), the user from passport-config.js is being printed before the user is read and returned in app.js file.

This is my app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const app = express();

const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email_id =>{
       mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE email_id= "+mysql.escape(email_id), (err, result, fields) => {

        if (!err){

            if(result.length==0)
                return null;
            else{
                console.log(result[0]]);
                return result[0];
            }
        }
        else
            console.log(err);
            return null;
    })
  }
)
```

And this is the passport-config file:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email_id, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email_id)
    console.log("logging user:"+user)                               //"This prints undefined.WHYY?!?!?"
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email_id' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.email_id))
  passport.deserializeUser((email_id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserByEmail(email_id))
  })

}

module.exports = initialize
```

This is the the terminal after submitting the login form:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server has started on port 3010
Connection Established Successfully
logging user:undefined
RowDataPacket {
  email_id: 'someuser@hotmail.com',
  password: '$2a$05$Gvyn0CPZ0u8i93rZ9TTVPOvDYGlFbkaxiwIeUZIKmOgvspyWYjySC',
  user_name: 'someuser',
  mobile_no: 8377564281,
  address: 'some address',
  type_id: 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer, as I'm having the exact same problem. But one thing I noticed is that in the original (YouTube video), he's not returning anything in

```
email => users.find(user => user.email === email)
```

or

```
id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
```

but the code you replaced it with is returning something.